# Subgaussian bounds for $X$ imply subgaussian bounds for $X-E(X)$

Tags: probability-theory

A random variable $X$ is called sub-gaussian, if there exist positive constants $C,c$ such that for all positive $\lambda$ we have $$P(|X|\geq \lambda)\leq Ce^{-c\lambda^2}.$$Now I'm reading a text, where it says that if a random variable is subgaussian,then the probability that "one is at least $\lambda$ standart deviations from the mean drops off like $ Ce^{-c\lambda^2}$".

How does this statement translate to a more formal one ? How can I prove it ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think that text has made a meaningless statement, since the correct interpretation of the definition of sub-Guassian is that there exist positice $C, c$ such that for *all* $\lambda: P(|X| \geq \lambda) \leq Ce^{-c\lambda^2}$.  So first, there is no specific variate to talk about being at least some number of standard deviations from the mean, and second, if there were, $\lambda$ is not some specific number, it is a "dummy" symbol used in the definition.

Comment: @MarkFischler  Sorry, that was my mistake, I forgot to mention how $\lambda$ was quantified. I couldn't understand your second sentence though, could you please elaborate ?

Comment: Let's take the first half:  Say I have a random variable $X$ chosen with some distribution; for concreteness, say a Gaussian with $f(x) \propto e^{-x^2/2}$.  So what would you mean to say "$X$ is at least half a standard deviation from the mean"?  We know what one standard deviation is (1), but what are we comparing to 1? Now consider the second half of the statement:  If we have a statement like "for all values of $k$, $k^2$ is positive, then you can write the question (in English) "is 5 greater than k", but that has no semantic meaning: $k$ just stands for some arbitrary number.

Comment: Indeed, unless the OP provides the text so that we can check it verbatim, there is no question here.

Comment: @Did Ok, I emailed the author of my notes that there perhaps was an error in his text an he emailed us an updated version back - I updated my question accordingly to reflect these changes. –

Comment: Then I guess the idea is that if $P(|X|\geq \lambda)\leq Ce^{-c\lambda^2}$ for every positive $\lambda$ for $X$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then $$P(|X-\mu|\geq \lambda\sigma)\leq C'e^{-c'\lambda^2},$$ for every positive $\lambda$, for some $(c',C')$ depending on $(c,C,\mu,\sigma)$. And this follows simply from the triangular inequality $$[|X-\mu|\geqslant\lambda\sigma]\subseteq[|X|\geqslant\lambda\sigma-|\mu|].$$